# Recursively rename files and directories

Tags: find, rename

I'm using this command to rename files:

```
for fname in *;
do
    mv "$fname" $(echo "$fname" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ')
done
```

But it only renames in the current directory. Let's say I have many directories, and each directory contains some other directories, and last directory tree contains files. I want to rename them with random characters.

I think `find . -type f` should work, and have tried it, but still did not get any working command.

Comment: Be aware that `echo` will insert a newline at end of of output, so modifying the sha1sum output with respect to what you would expect for the bare string.

Answer (score 8):

With find:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'SHELL COMMAND' {} \;
```

This invokes `SHELL COMMAND` on each found file in turn; the file name is `"$0"`. Thus:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    mv "$0" "${0%/*}/$(printf "%s\n" "${0##*/}" | sha1sum | cut -d" " -f1)"
' {} \;
```

(Note the use of `printf` rather than `echo`, in case you have a file called `-e` or `-n` or a few other problematic cases that `echo` mangles.)

You can make this a little faster by invoking the shell in batches.

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for x; do
      mv "$x" "${x%/*}/$(printf "%s\n" "${x##*/}" | sha1sum | cut -d" " -f1)";
    done' _ {} +
```

In zsh, there's an easy way to match all the files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively. The `.` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) restricts the matches to regular files, and `D` includes dot files.

```
for x in **/*(.D); do mv …; done
```

In bash ≥4, you can run `shopt -s globstar` and use `**/*` to match all files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively. You'll need to filter regular files in the loop.

```
shopt -s globstar; GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
for x in **/*; do if [[ -f $x ]]; then mv …; done
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles... About 'echo': interesting, and noteworthy: `x="-n"; echo "$x"` treats the -n as an opiton and prints nothing, but `x="-n "; echo "$x "` prints `-n ` with the trailing space..  Thinking about it, it makes sense, as "-n" resolves to a bare -n option, and "-n " doesn't... but echo doesn't have the special "--" option to protect from this..

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bash 4+, you can do:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for fname in **/*; do 
  if [ -f "$fname" ]; then
    mv ...
  fi
done
```

From the Bash Hacker's Wiki:

> There's a new shell option globstar. When enabled, Bash will perform recursive globbing on ** – this means it matches all directories and files from the current position in the filesystem, rather that only the current level.

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/bash4

Comment: Don't this glob match only directory, but the user wants only files?

Comment: @enzotib Indeed, it did. I have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, this syntax was taken from zsh, which, IMHO, is a far better shell.

Comment: [globstar in bash 4 follows directory symlinks](http://en.chys.info/2009/04/globstar-in-bash-4-follows-symlinks/) .. I'm getting filenames like this: `ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/ztest/b/z....` ... It doesn't crash, oddly enough... maybe it is somehow limited in the number of loop-de-loops it does...

Comment: Ouch: that is not pretty...

Comment: why is it `**/*` rather than `*/**`?

Answer (score 2):

Create a helper script /tmp/tmp.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv "$1" $(echo "$1" | sha1sum | cut -f1 -d' ')
```

make it executable, then invoke it:

```
find . -type f -execdir /tmp/tmp.sh {} ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

This handles all whitespace ok...

```
set -f; IFS= 
while read -r -d $'\0' fname ;do
    mv ...
done < <(find . -type f -name '*' -print0)
set +f; IFS=$' \t\n' # you don't have to reset unless it effects subsequent code
```