# Replace a substring of filenames in a directory

Tags: shell, rename

There exists a directory, which includes several levels of sub-directories.  Under these directories, there are a set of files whose names include a common word, e.g, `.cc`. How can I replace  the `.cc` in the names of these files with `.cpp`?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18455/recursive-rename-files-and-directories/

Comment: @jasonwryan The first part is the same, but that one doesn't say anything about how to string-replace in a filename, so it probably makes sense to leave them separate

Comment: @Michael You are right: I had conflated it with another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say the files "names include a common word," I am assuming that you are referring to the fact that they share the `.cc` extension: if so, using [Gilles' answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18455/recursive-rename-files-and-directories/18529#18529) you could construct a command that would achieve your goal:

```
 find -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do [ "${file##*.}" = "cc" ] && 
    mv -- "$file" "${file%.cc}.ccp"; done
    ' -- {} +
```

See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753823/how-do-i-apply-a-shell-command-to-many-files-in-nested-and-poorly-escaped-subdi/754940#754940) for more detail

Answer (score 3):

In zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(**/)(*).cc' '$1$2.cpp'
```

In bash ≥4:

```
for x in **/*.cc; do mv "$x" "${x%.cc}.cpp"; done
```

In any shell:

```
find -name '*.cc' -exec sh -c 'for x; do mv "$x" "${x%.cc}.cpp"; done' _ {} +
```

Simpler, and portable to older systems, but slightly slower:

```
find -name '*.cc' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.cc}.cpp"' {} \;
```

[See this answer for explanations.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18455/recursive-rename-files-and-directories/18529#18529)