# Rename multiple directories at once

Tags: shell-script, find

I have a project with many directories named `proj`

```
$ find . -iname proj
./include/proj
./src/proj
./lib/proj
./share/proj
./doc/proj
```

I want to rename all these directories to `test` with `-exec mv`. I came up with `find . -iname proj -exec mv {} test` but it doesn't work

Comment: `find . -iname proj -print0 | xargs -0 rename.ul proj test`

Comment: one way: `find . -depth -type d -name proj -execdir mv proj test \;` - you need `depth` and `execdir` - for details see _Gilles_' answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46344)... there's plenty of examples on this site, I just picked the first result in google

Comment: @don_crissti Suppose for that case (with exact name) will be enough `find . -name proj -execdir mv {} test \;`

Comment: @Costas - that would work in this particular case but `find` will still complain (_No such file or directory_), just use `depth`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -depth -iname proj -type d -execdir mv {} test \;
```

You need a `find` implementation with support for the non-standard `-execdir` predicate, but `find` implementations that support `-iname` generally also support `-execdir` in my experience.