# linux find and rename items with backslash not working as expected

Tags: bash, find, rename

I have tried a couple of approaches to find and rename some files that hold a backslash (mind you these files generated from a web app do not have the quoets) in a directory.  I've tried with find and substitutions but they seem to fail at the parent level.  It's basically like it rename the parent, but then fails to descend after to child folders because its referencing the older parent name when descending?

Folder Structure:

```
'ano\ther' -> 'chi\ld'
```

When I run:

```bash
for file in `find . -name '*\\\*'`; do mv -v "$file" "${file/\\/}"; done`
```

or

```bash
find . -exec rename 's/\\//g' {} +
```

or

```bash
find . -name "*\\\*" -exec rename 's/\\//g' {} +
```

They pretty much all say the same error, but do rename the parent or present dir, just fail on descending.

```
Can't rename ./ano\ter/yo\yo ./anoter/yoyo: No such file or directory
```

What would I be missing in my command?

Comment: ... see [How do I get this find and rename command to work with subdirectories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46390/65304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

- [not loop over `find`'s output like that](/q/321697)
- avoid the deprecated `` `...` `` form of command substitution
- rename leaves before the branches they're on
- only remove the `\`s in the name of the file, not its full path
- avoid double quotes when wanting literal backslashes

So:

```
find . -depth -name '*\\*' -exec rename -d 's/\\//g' {} +
```

(here assuming a perl-based variant of `rename` and one that accepts that `-d` option to only rename the base name).

Or:

```
find . -depth -name '*\\*' -exec zsh -c '
  for file do
    mv -v -- $file $file:h/${file:t:gs/\\/}
  done' zsh {} +
```

Or in zsh, just:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -v '(**/)(*\\*)(#qD)' '$1$2:gs/\\/'
```

Here using the csh-style `$var:s/string/replacement/` (with `g` to repeat), but you could also use the ksh-style `${var//pattern/replacement}` (with `//` for the repeating form) if you preferred.

`zmv` does a depth-first traversal by default as that's what you generally want, the `(#qD)` is to also consider hidden files. `zmv` will also do some sanity checks and not rename anything if some problems are detected like if there's both a `a\bc` and `a\b\c` file which would both be renamed to `abc`.

Comment: As the major reason not to loop over `find`'s output is that file names can contain (almost) any character, and this question is explicitly about weird characters in file names, I think that is very appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide several examples.  I used `find . -depth -name '*\\*' -exec rename -d 's/\\//g' {} +` and it worked like a charm.  So I guess my two problems I had.  no -depth and adding triple backslash in '*\\\*' after -name was looking also at the path?  as your comment of "only remove the \s in the name of the file, not its full path"

Comment: Inside backtick, there's an extra level of backslash handling even inside single quotes so you need 4 (or 3) backslashes for 2 to be passed to find, but using command substitution with split+glob is wrong as explained in the linked Q&A. `-name` looks at the name, but `-exec cmd {} +` passes the whole path and it's only the backslashes in the tail (as in the `$file:t`) you want to rename, not the head (`$file:h`).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that error message comes because you're trying to remove both 'es at once, and the directory './anoter' probably doesn't exist.

You can handle all the files in your directory structure by just adding `-type f`  to your find. But then you'll still have the directories, if you know that you only have one level of subdirectories (or at least only 'es in the names in one level) you can just use `-type d`  to find, but if you have e.g. `ano\ther/d\ir/` the command will fail with the same error.

You might get something to work with using `-execdir` instead on `-exec` (and using `-depth`), but I've never tried `-execdir` so I'm just going on what a quick reading of the manpage suggests. Thinking about it, I'm not even sure you need to handle the files first if you do that.