# moving string from filenames with sed or rename them with rename

Tags: sed, rename

I have a bunch of video-files in one folder , that has a double suffix avi.avi.

```
find /home/alex/Filme/  -type f -name '*.avi.avi' 
/home/alex/Filme/Super 8.avi.avi
/home/alex/Filme/Exit - A Night From Hell.avi.avi
/home/alex/Filme/Der Plan.avi.avi
/home/alex/Filme/Ich.bin.Nummer.4.2011.avi.avi
snipp
```

I try to remove the double string with following "Script"

```
 #!/bin/bash
    for i in `find $HOME/Filme -type f -name '*avi.avi' -print0` 

    do 
        sed -e 's/'*.avi.avi'/'*.avi'/g'
 done
```

Or is a better way to achive this with rename, like this?

```
find $HOME/Filme -type f -name '*avi.avi' -print0 -exec  sh -c rename -v 's/*.avi.avi/*.avi/g' {} \;
```

I'am not sure if the foldername will be preserved.
Yes I found several questions and answers for this, but I have problems to adapt it to my case.

[example for Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18455/recursively-rename-files-and-directories)

Does one of my approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
find $HOME/Filme -type f -name '*avi.avi' -exec \
  sh -c "rename -v 's/\.avi\.avi$/.avi/'" {} \;
```

(The argument to `rename` is a regular expression substitution; and the `/g` option would only be useful if you wanted to substitute every occurrence in a matching file name; but by definition, there can only be one match at the very end.)

Perhaps more usefully you can batch this, and maybe just use `mv` for improved portability.

```
find $HOME/Filme -type f -name '*avi.avi' -exec \
  sh -c 'for f; do mv -v "$f" "${f%.avi}"; done' _ {} +
```

If there is no need to traverse subdirectories,

```
for f in $HOME/Filme/*.avi.avi; do
    mv -v "$f" "${f%.avi}"
done
```

Comment: `find "$HOME/Filme" -type f -name \*.avi.avi -exec rename -v 's/.avi$//' {} +` as `rename` can take multiple arguments.

Comment: Perl `rename` isn't available on all systems so the `sh` is better suited. `+` there is GNUism but can easily be replaced by `\;` for compatibility reasons

Answer (score 1):

With simple ***rename*** (*Perl* implementation) command:

```
rename 's/(.*\.avi)\.avi$/$1/' /home/alex/Filme/*.avi.avi
```

Or with just removing the last `.avi` section:

```
rename 's/\.avi$//' /home/alex/Filme/*.avi.avi
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this code to rename such files

```
rename -v "s/\.avi$//g" *
```

Comment: ... you shouldn't, since it will remove **all** `.avi` suffixes, as well as non-suffix matches such as *ravi*shankar

Comment: This is rename command, not removing anything. Should he change the format in comply with his needs

Comment: It *is* removing any character followed by "avi" in all file names, which is not what the OP is asking. Fixing your regex so it doesn´t do unwanted damage isn't hard, but the other answers here already sort of cover that.